# Autofocus on the first empty TextField Mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve autofocus functionality when fields are empty   ..
but in this situation autoFocus always works

```
<Controller
                      name="sum"
                      control={control}
                      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                        <TextField
                          value={money || value}
                          onChange={onChange}
                          error={!!errors?.sum}
                          autoFocus={!value}
                          helperText={errors?.sum && errors.sum?.message}
                          InputProps={{
                            placeholder: 'Например, 100 000 000',
                            endAdornment: (
                              <InputAdornment position="end">
                                <SvgRoubleIcon />
                              </InputAdornment>
                            ),
                            inputComponent: CurrencyInput,
                          }}
               
                        />
                      )}
                    />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when fields are empty then I want to add autoFocus

Answer (score 0):

Have you try use it like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

import "./index.css";

function App() {
  const ref = React.createRef(null);
  const defaultValues = {
    firstName: '',
  };
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({defaultValues});

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          name="firstName"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { value, ref, ...field } }) => {
            console.log(field,value)
            return <TextField
              {...field}
              inputRef={ref}
              value={value}
              id="firstName"
              autoComplete="fname"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              autoFocus={!value}
              error={!!errors.firstName}
              label="First Name"
          />
          }}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Live example is [Real example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-mui-autocomplete-forked-l9pst1?file=/src/index.js:0-1379)

Comment: value - from where you get

Comment: I have update my answer , if you change defaultValues firstName , you can see that focus will not active after the mount @Jhon